# SmartGit authentication to bare repository fails, while push from commandline works

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, smartgit

I've added a remote bare repository using commandline:

```
git add remote production ssh://username@domain.com/path/to/repo.git
```

I'm able to push to the repository using:

```
git push production master
```

Now I'd like to push from SmartGit:

1. I right click my local master-branch and choose **Push To ...**.
2. In the window I select the production repository and click **Push**.
3. A dialog is shown asking me for private SSH key and passphrase. I point to the private key and type the passphrase then click **Login**.
4. The dialog is shown again and I click **Login** once again.
5. SmartGit display an error in the Output-window:

   ```
   Push: Could not read from remote repository.
   /var/www/website> git push --porcelain --progress --recurse-submodules-check production refs/heads/master
   Could not read from remote repository.
   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   Could not read from remote repository.
   ```

I've checked that I have the correct access rights and that the repository exists. Also private key has only read/write permissions for the onwer (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`).

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when configuring to **Use system SSH client** in the **Preferences**, section **Authentication**?

Comment: @mstrap Worked! First the log throw an error: `ssh-askpass [...] no such file or directory`. So I did `sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass`. Then tried new push like described above. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to write an answer based on mstrap suggestion and mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable **Use system SSH client** in the **Preferences**, section **Authentication**
2. Install ssh-askpass: `sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass`
3. Then push again ...